# Desplegar spring boot aplicación VPS Java 1.8 Tomcat 8

Tags: webservice, tomcat, java-8, deployment, spring-boot

tenemos un servicio desarrollado con spring boot, con java 1.8 y tomcat 8, necesitamos desplegarlo en un sitio web. Ya que tenemos que guardar muchas imágenes, optamos por pagar un vps. Alguien nos podrìa orientar que debemos de tener en cuenta. La  idea es contratar un servidor linux y correr una aplicaciòn en angular que consuma el servicio. Gracias